# How to get the version in Day.js?

Tags: dayjs

I switched from moment.js to Day.js because moment.js is [deprecated](https://momentjs.com/docs/) (They won't add new features and it is recommanded to switch to a different library).

In moment.js it was possible to get the version like this:

```
moment.version
```

and for the tz plugin:

```
moment.tz.version
```

But this isn't possible in Day.js:

```
dayjs.version
dayjs.tz.version
```

It returns "undefined". Any ideas?

I am using version `2.0.0-alpha.4` because I want to use ES6 imports.

Here is the snippet:

```html
<div id="moh">waiting</div>
<script type="module">
import dayjs from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@2.0.0-alpha.4/dist/esm/index.mjs";
document.getElementById("moh").textContent = dayjs.version == undefined ? "undefined" : dayjs.version;
</script>
```

Comment: Don't think you can, if you look at the source of a CDN link, the version is not included.

Answer (score 0):

In Day.js, you can check the version using the version property of the dayjs object.

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

console.log(dayjs.version);
```

This should log the version of Day.js in the console.

As for the dayjs.tz object, it's not part of the core Day.js library. Instead, it's provided by the dayjs/plugin/timezone plugin, which you can import separately like this:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';

dayjs.extend(timezone);

console.log(dayjs.tz.version);
```

This should log the version of the timezone plugin in the console.

Note that dayjs.tz will be undefined until you extend Day.js with the timezone plugin.

Comment: As I already wrote in the question I tried this and it doesn't work.